# How do I create a "report" or dashboard from many different lists in one site collection?

Tags: web-part, list-view, view, dashboard

**SharePoint 2010**

I've been asked to make a "report" (what I'm envisioning to be a dashboard of sorts) using 6 different lists in the same site collection.

Each list is a different product and contains unique columns, but they also have a handful of columns in common.  The report will be grouped by each of the 6 products, with approximately 8 fields to display per product.

I'm able to set up lists and views without a problem, but I'm not sure how to combine all of the data into a single view.

My initial thought is to create a new page with a Web Part that pulls all the data together, but I'm not sure how to pull multiple sources into one Web Part, or, more accurately, which Web Part to use.

Another potential option would be to create a dashboard with multiple list view Web Parts, and I looked at the Site Aggregator (a previous admin set up a page for each product with a list view), but the request is really to get all products/information into one view.

**Question:** How do I roll up data from 6 different lists into one view/webpart/dashboard?

**Constraints:** Can use SPD2010 or SharePoint interface only; no JavaScript/JQuery/Visual Studio/etc.

Comment: are you have SSRS or PerformancePoint ?!

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have access to either of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content query web part. It is a standard webpart that rolls up content within the same site collection.

You can roll up items from lists, documents, pages or other elements, provided they are in one single site collection.

In version 2010, using SharePoint Designer 2010 you can also create Data View Webparts.

Comment: How do I pull in multiple lists?  They are all in a single site collection.  

I've edited the Web Part, then go to the Query section and have options to "Show items from all sites in this site collection" (way too much information), "Show items from the following site and all subsites" (can't seem to filter by custom columns), and "Show items from the following list" (too exclusive, doesn't include all lists).

Comment: you need to compile all parts of QUERY and PRESENTATION. When it asks for List Type, select Custom List (I suppose). Content Type: List Content Type, Show items of content type: ITEM. Apply filters and sorting as necessary